# How to check if a file is written to terminal?

Tags: python, unix

Is there some way to check if the output of a python process is being written to file? I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
if is_writing_to_terminal:
    sys.stdout.write('one thing')
else: 
    sys.stdout.write('another thing')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `os.isatty()` to check whether a file descriptor is a terminal:

```
if os.isatty(sys.stdout.fileno()):
    sys.stdout.write('one thing')
else: 
    sys.stdout.write('another thing')
```

Comment: hmm, so is there any difference between `os.isatty(sys.stdout.fileno())` and [`sys.stdout.isatty()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.isatty)?

Answer (score 2):

Use `os.isatty`. That expects a file descriptor (fd), which can be obtained with the `fileno` member.

```
>>> from os import isatty
>>> isatty(sys.stdout.fileno())
True
```

If you want to support arbitrary file-likes (e.g. `StringIO`), then you have to check whether the file-like has an associated fd since not all file-likes do:

```
hasattr(f, "fileno") and isatty(f.fileno())
```